# How to add "send to" Option with JFileChooser

Tags: java, windows, swing, jfilechooser

I am working on a small project towards my grad, where I need to have "send to" option with JFileChooser. I want this option to be appeared on Right Click event. Kindly suggest how to go about it?

Note: I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You might use JPopupMenu

For example,

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;

public class PopupMenuExample extends JPanel {

  public JPopupMenu popup;

  public PopupMenuExample() {
    popup = new JPopupMenu();
    ActionListener menuListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Popup menu item ["
            + event.getActionCommand() + "] was pressed.");
        if(event.getActionCommand().equals("Send To")) {
            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
            int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
            // your logic here
        }
      }
    };
    JMenuItem item;
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Send To"));
    item.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Left"));
    item.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Center"));
    item.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Right"));
    item.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Full"));
    item.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);
    popup.addSeparator();
    popup.add(item = new JMenuItem("Settings . . ."));
    item.addActionListener(menuListener);

    popup.setLabel("Justification");
    popup.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
    popup.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupPrintListener());

    addMouseListener(new MousePopupListener());
  }

  // An inner class to check whether mouse events are the popup trigger
  class MousePopupListener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      checkPopup(e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
      checkPopup(e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
      checkPopup(e);
    }

    private void checkPopup(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
        popup.show(PopupMenuExample.this, e.getX(), e.getY());
      }
    }
  }

  // An inner class to show when popup events occur
  class PopupPrintListener implements PopupMenuListener {
    public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Popup menu will be visible!");
    }

    public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Popup menu will be invisible!");
    }

    public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Popup menu is hidden!");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Popup Menu Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(new PopupMenuExample());
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```